# FTP-Plugin for Gedit

Tags: ftp, gedit

I tried to install the Ftp plugin in Gedit, but I don't get it. 
I followed up this site:

http://code.google.com/p/gedit-ftp-browser/

Suggestions?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

You may want to provide more specific error information, but, make sure you have the right version of Gedit. That plugin is for 2.x and Gedit is currently in the 3.x branch.

Second, the File Browser plugin shipped with Gedit can handle FTP (and SSH and pretty much any virtual filesystem supported by your OS). Just open up your file browser and select `File` > `Connect to Server` or execute the command `nautilus-connect-server`. Once you've connected to a server it will show up in the Gedit file browser pane. You can always bookmark frequently used connections for quick access in Gedit.